# Initial value problem of the form $y^{\prime} = cos(y)x, y(0) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I just got started on differential equations and the initial value problem and solved some simpler IVPs in the form of for example $y{\prime} = \frac{2x}{(1+x^2)y}, y(0) = -2$. Now I'm stuck at the problem: $y^{\prime} = cos(y)x, y(0) = 0$, as I'm able to integrate the seperable equation and get $ln (|sec(y) + tan(y)|) = \frac{x^2}{2}+C$ with $C$ being a constant, but I do not know how to solve for $y$ and fullfill the initial value of $y(0) = 0$. If anybody could help me with this, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: $y$ has disappeared altogether in your answer. Did you mean $\log|\sec y+\tan y|$? In any event, you get $C$ by putting in $x=0$ and $y=0$.

Comment: Of course, I just edited it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: $\ln(|\sec(0)+\tan(0)|)=0^2+C  $ You get $C=0$ since $\ln 1 =0$

Comment: @Isham I dont think I can do that at this point since I don't know that y(x) looks like, yet...

Comment: Oh yes you can do it. Do you know what an implicit form is ? You don't need an explicit form for y to find the constant c. Sometimes it's hard to find such an explicit form and we leave the answer in implicit form psyph

Comment: @Isham So would I just say the IVP is solved with $ln(|sec(y) + tan(y)|) = \frac{x^2}{2}$?

Comment: Yep or you can use ad2004's answer ...with tan function and arctan

Comment: But if I were to take the arctan, my answer would depend on $n \in \mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "depend on $n\in\bf R$". What's $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This identity might be useful:

$\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4} \right)=\sec \theta + \tan \theta$

For more details see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

Also, shouldn't the left side be functions of $y$ in your solution?

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I made a typo. And yes, that identity helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What is amazing in this problem is that we can use the tangent half-angle substition.

Let $$y=2 \tan ^{-1}(z)\implies y'=\frac{2 z'}{z^2+1}$$ which make the equation to be
$$2 z'+x \left(z^2-1\right)=0\implies \log(z^2-1)=-x+c\implies 2 \tanh ^{-1}(z)=-x+c$$ whih finally makes
$$y=2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\tanh \left(c_1+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)\right)$$ and the condition leads to $c_1=0$.